# Function for building all subsets

Tags: c#

I want to create a function that creates a list of all subsets. for example :

```
if list candid in step 1 is: {1,2,4,5}
output: {12,14,15,24,25,45}

and if list candid in step 2 is: {12,14,25,45} (15,24 deleted)
output: {124,125,145}
```

I wrote code below, but this code only works to build candid step 2.

```
            for (int i = 0; i < candid.Count; i++)
            {
                for (int j = i + 1; j < candid.Count; j++)
                {
                    if(ratecandid[i] > 50)
                    {
                        candid_new.Add(int.Parse(string.Concat(candid[i], candid[j])));
                    }
                }
            }
```

I do not think it's a good code. Can you provide an appropriate solution that works well for other lists ?

**Updateed :**

In general, we have a set of numbers. (1,2,4,5), In another function for this set is defined a rate(100,101,94,172) (94 for 4) .If the rate of each number is less than 50, then this number is not selected .So firstly, all members are selected, and we must create all possible subsets. {12,14,15,24,25,45}. Again, for these members, the rate is determined, (60,74,42,36,74,63,). If the rate of each number (rate 12 is 60) is less than 50, then this number is not selected. So this collection is selected {12,14,25,45}, now, we must create all possible subsets. {124,125,145}.

the set must be in order(like : alphabetical order) and a recurring member should not exist. 121 and 122 have recurring members

Answer (score 0, accepted):

here I m showing you a method which will accept a number list and using that list, it will provide new List.

New list will take care of

- Alphabetical order of number
- No duplicate numbers
- No recurring numbers

you will only need to check your rate's part of logic to elemental those numbers who have rate less than 50

```
private static List<int> GetNewList(List<int> numberList)
{
    List<int> newNumList = new List<int>();
    for (int i = 0; i < numberList.Count - 1; i ++)
    {
        for(int j = i+1; j < numberList.Count; j++)
        {
            string number = "";
            foreach (char ch in numberList[j].ToString())
            {
                number = numberList[i].ToString() + ch;

                if (!IsNumRecurring(number))
                {
                    number = String.Concat(number.OrderBy(c => c));
                    int num = int.Parse(number);

                    if (!newNumList.Contains(num))
                        newNumList.Add(num);
                }
            }
        }
    }

    //Now we should check the same thing in reverse order on list.
    for (int i = numberList.Count - 1; i > 0; i--)
    {
        for (int j = i -1; j >= 0; j--)
        {
            string number = "";
            foreach (char ch in numberList[j].ToString())
            {
                number = numberList[i].ToString() + ch;

                if (!IsNumRecurring(number))
                {
                    number = String.Concat(number.OrderBy(c => c));
                    int num = int.Parse(number);

                    if (!newNumList.Contains(num))
                        newNumList.Add(num);
                }
            }
        }
    }
    return newNumList;
}

//here we will check if number is recurring
private static bool IsNumRecurring(string num)
{
    return num.Any(c => num.Where(ch => ch == c).Count() > 1);
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your guidance, All things work properly, but a problem, for example : candidate in step 2 is `{12,14,15,24,26,46}`. We need this output : {124,125,126,145,146,156,245,246} But the output of your solution is equal to: `{124,125,126,145,146,156,246}`  >> 245 was not added. There is some minor changes in your code. changes is : [link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ah3CY.jpg), I think the problem is that we do not derive from the **father list** (1,2,4,5,6)

Comment: @Amin yes, because as you see concatenating logic goes from left to right in list, and in such case 245 was not possible case. I think this was missed as in question it was never discussed (even in comments and examples too we have missed such case)

Comment: and about changes, what is `minutil` you added ? and also as you have changed list from int to string, and now you are adding "," between every digit in string.. if this is what your final requirement? why didn't you  put that in question only.. you would have got direct answer for that.

Comment: And won't there be 456 and 256 ?

Comment: Yes you are right. Some things were not said, I apologize, Because the other candidates, this problem appeared, minutil is = number 50 , we changed list from int to string, and adding "," between every digit in string, Because we encountered a problem in search, For example, if the numbers 245 and 478 are combined, we create 245478, then there is 547 (24'547'8) in the created number, that this is a problem, also 456 and 256 can be present, but have not been added because if condition `if (arraytwu[i] >= minutil`

Comment: @Amin , i have updated code, you may check it. here you will have to add `minutil` by yourself. let me know if it works properly or not

Comment: 25 , 45 is not in list candidate, So now we do not need to add 245 , 456 to the list, I think that I did not say completely in the last line

Comment: Is it possible for you that solve my last problem, please

Comment: @Amin my current answer is solution for that only.. what more you want me to do? to add rate logic too ?

Comment: if input is : {12,14,15,24,26,46}. We need this output : {124,125,126,145,146,156,245,246} , but in your solution, output is {124,125,126,145,146,156,245,246,256,456} that 25 and 45 not in input list, then It does not need that 256 and 456 should not be on the outpu list. Do you comprehend my meaning?

Answer (score 0):

As your computation of the rate is still unknow here is a partial aswer that will get you all possible result:

```
var result = new List<int> { };
for (int i = 0; i < candid.Count(); i++)
{
    for (int j = i + 1; j < candid.Count(); j++)
    {
        var value =
            int.Parse(
                new string(
                    string.Concat(candid[i], candid[j])
                        .OrderBy(x => x)
                        .Distinct()
                        .ToArray()
                    )
                );

        if (true)
        {
            result.Add(value);
        }
    }
}
return result.Distinct().ToArray();
```

The new part is basically:

-Once the int are concatenate.
-Remove duplicate digit in it.
-The order them.

-If it satisfy your condition then add it to the result.

-before returning the result make sure it's has no duplicate. And voila.

Comment: Last Distinct can be remove if you add a Contains check in the rate condition.